# Hyperledger Composer issue identity but missing business card

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working in a proof of concept with a Node.js application and 'composer-client' npm module.

I have tried different commands such as adding a participant, adding an asset and performing a transaction and everything seems to work correctly.

However, when I try to issue a new identity I do not get the results that I expect. I execute my Node.js application with the following code:

```
var businessNetwork = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
return businessNetwork.connect('admin@tutorial-network')
.then(() => {
  return businessNetwork.issueIdentity('org.acme.biznet.Trader#Trader_001', 'usr001')
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(`userID = ${result.userID}`);
  console.log(`userSecret = ${result.userSecret}`);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Then, UserId and UserSecret are displayed at console log. After that, I try to do a ping to Business Network:

```
var businessNetwork = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
return businessNetwork.connect('usr001@tutorial-network')
.then(() => {
  return businessNetwork.ping();
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(`participant = ${result.participant ? result.participant : '<no participant found>'}`);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
{ Error: Card not found: usr001@tutorial-network
at IdCard.fromDirectory.catch.cause (/home/user.name/git_repositories/nodejs/first.blockchain.test/node_modules/composer-common/lib/cardstore/filesystemcardstore.js:73:27)
at <anonymous>
cause: 
{ Error: Unable to read card directory: /home/user.name/.composer/cards/user001@tutorial-network
```

If I execute the command `composer identity list -c admin@tutorial-network`, I get the following output:

```
$class:      org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity
  identityId:  9b49f67c262c0ae23e1e0c4a8dc61c4a12b5119df2b6a49fa2e02fa56b8818c3
  name:        usr001
  issuer:      27c582d674ddf0f230854814b7cfd04553f3d0eac55e37d915386c614a5a1de9
  certificate: 
  state:       ISSUED
  participant: resource:org.acme.biznet.Trader#Trader_001
```

But, I am not able to find the business card.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I'm using composer 0.15.1.

```
var businessNetwork = new BusinessNetworkConnection();

return businessNetwork.connect('admin@carauction-network')
.then(() => {
  return businessNetwork.ping();
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(`participant = ${result.participant ? result.participant : '<no participant found>'}`);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Output is like this

```
linux1@fabric:~/eventclient$ node event.js
participant = org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin
```

You may need to import ID card to wallet ?

```
composer card import --file networkadmin.card
```

Comment: Once you issued your file.card, did you import it to wallet? In case of yes, where is it saved that file when it is issued from node.js code? I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue late last week. Part of the upgrade instructions from V0.14 to V0.15 states that we have to delete the (if existing) `~/.composer`, `~/.composer-connection-profiles` and `~/.composer-credentials`. I skipped that step on my first upgrade to v01.5 and encountered the error you are seeing. Went back and deleted those three folders, reinstalled the binaries and rechecked docker image status. Error went away and has not reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You named the new card `user001`, not `user001@@tutorial-network`. Try connecting with just `user001` as your connection card name.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to create a card for the participant using the enrollment secret obtained from the javascript.

```
composer card create -u usr001 -s <enrollment_secret> -f usr001.card -n tutorial-network -p connection.json
```

You probably created the connection.json needed in some step before in the tutorial you are following. If this file is not available explicitly, you may get it from the composer wallet. In the current version, it can be located in /home/your_user/.composer/cards/. If you are only following the tutorial, any connection.json in this directory will do.
After that, you must add the credential created to the wallet using:

```
composer card import -f usr001.card
```

Your code for testing the issued identity is correct.